# How to delete records if user_mail column value doesn't contain keywords like gmail, yahoo, hotmail in mysql

Tags: mysql

In **Mysql**, there is a **Users** table with column name **user_mail**. I want to **delete** all records in **user_mail** column which does not contain keywords like **hotmail, gmail, yahoo**.

And also I want to remove all related record in other tables.

Note: It is a **wordpress** DB.

Comment: First part is easy.  For the second part, you should tell us what the schema is and if you have any on cascade delete setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM [Users]
WHERE [user_mail] NOT LIKE '%hotmail% '
OR [user_mail] NOT LIKE '%gmail% '
OR [user_mail] NOT LIKE '%yahoo% '
```

And to delete the related records, make the relation you want to delete `DELETE CASCADE`

EDIT:

```
DELETE FROM [Users]
WHERE [user_mail] LIKE '%hotmail% '
OR [user_mail] LIKE '%gmail% '
OR [user_mail] LIKE '%yahoo% '
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_mail NOT LIKE '%hotmail%' OR user_mail NOT LIKE '%gmail%' OR user_mail NOT LIKE '%yahoo%'` return all rows which includes the user_mail contains gmail/hotmail/yahoo. @Svenmarim

Comment: I'm sorry, remove the 'NOT' from every line